# Use webpage link to access mobile GPS app and pass current location to the app

Tags: android, ios, mobile, gps, html

My objective is to use my current webpage to access a native mobile gps app, from a link on the webpage, and have that link send my current location and destination location to the application. It must all be done from my web page. For example I click a building address link and it takes me to that building thru the application. The user will have to be browsing on a mobile device.

Comment: Just need to know how to pass information from one to another. Examples are always welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the mobile browsers support the GEO location API and you can use their location to center a map with Virtual Earth or Google and of course add items you need to add to the map like pushpins etc. I have a blog post about it:

http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2012/05/25/A-Study-Using-The-HTML5-Geolocation-API.aspx